# Timer in a Child Thread in PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

First off, I'm very new to Python and Pyside.  In order to do a bit of self-improvement, I'm trying to get a QTimer to execute every second in a child thread of my PySide program (at the moment I just want it to print "hi!" to a terminal every second without freezing the main window).

I tried converting the [example I found on the Qt Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e) from C++ to Python/PySide, but since I don't really know C++ I assume I converted it incorrectly and that's why it's not working properly.

At the moment, the doWork() function only seems to execute once and then never again.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to execute a function every second in PySide without freezing the main window?

Here's the code (I have removed some main window code to increase clarity):

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
from client_gui import Ui_MainWindow

statsThread = QtCore.QThread()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        #setup GUI
        self.setupUi(self)
        #start thread to update GUI
        self.statsThread = updateStatsThread()
        self.statsThread.start(QtCore.QThread.TimeCriticalPriority)

class updateGuiWithStats(QtCore.QObject):
    def Worker(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork())
        timer.start(1000)

    def doWork(self):
        print "hi!"

class updateStatsThread (QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        updater = updateGuiWithStats()
        updater.Worker()
        self.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Masci already pointed out the fix you needed for your `timer.timeout.connect`, but I see more issues than just that.

No need to create a global QThread that is never used:

```
statsThread = QtCore.QThread()
```

Your QTimer is being garbage collected right away because its created without a parent, and you aren't saving it within your class. This is why even after you fix your timer connection, it will still not work... Try:

```
class UpdateGuiWithStats(QtCore.QObject):

    def startWorker(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork)
        self.timer.start(1000)
```

Also, use UpperCase for the first letter of classes, and camelCase for methods. You are doing a mixture of both ways.

A couple of notes based on that link you provided, your example, and other comments on here... You can use just a QTimer as a solution if your `doWork()` is very light and will not block your main event loop with a bunch of data crunching, sleeping, etc. If it does, then `doWork()` will need to be moved to a QThread, as your example is doing. But at that point it is somewhat unnecessary to use an event loop, and a QTimer in a separate class that calls its own work. This all could be consolidated into a single class, something like:

```
class UpdateStatsThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UpdateStatsThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self._running = False

    def run(self):
        self._running = True
        while self._running:
            self.doWork()
            self.msleep(1000)

    def stop(self, wait=False):
        self._running = False
        if wait:
            self.wait()

    def doWork(self):
        print "hi!"
```

Comment: You're correct in assuming that I would like to do more in `doWork()` than just calling `print "foo"` or something.  With that in mind, I implemented the revised `UpdateStatsThread()` class that you wrote.  However, when I go to quit the thread, I get a message that the thread was destroyed while running.  I assume that's because of me quitting the thread while `time.sleep(1)` is still running.  Is there a good way of quitting the thread and avoiding that message?

Comment: Ya totally. Its definitely because python is destroying the object before it has really finished. I updated my answer to add an optional wait to the stop() method. I also updated the sleep to use the QThread.msleep()

Answer (score 1):

in `updateGuiWithStats` class, `Worker` method:

```
timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork())
```

should be

```
timer.timeout.connect(self.doWork)
```

You are connecting timeout signal to `None` (the return value of `doWork()` method), and I think this is why it is executed only once: `doWork` is called during the connection and nomore. When you make connections, remember to connect the function name (in Pythonics words, the callable object) and not the function call.

By the way, even if the above solved your problem, you should avoid using threads since QTimer already does by its own you need. In the [docs you linked](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects#c2e33c61ced29e1eb1bee9a1671f202e), the first answer to the *When shouldn’t I use threads?* question is: Timers.

Comment: Also, the solution to use QTimer instead of QThread isn't a fix-all solution. It only works if your `doWork()` is fast so that it can get executed not block the main event loop. If its a heavy call, then it will still end up blocking your event loop every time it gets called. Thus, you would then need to move that functionality into a thread.

Comment: Agree, but for the needs of the OP I think threading is overkill

Comment: Thats kind of an unfounded assumption. How do you know what his `doWork()` really does? Its obviously not a simple print statement. That was just his example code. The needs of the OP could very well require a thread